# SharePoint form field control pass the list id value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

```
<SharePoint:FormField  runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}"  
   ControlMode="New"  
   FieldName="PID_NonLookup" List Id="need dynamically">
```

In this code I don't want to set the list id manually. How to pass the list id dynamically. Because if I manually enter the list id while moving one environment to another facing issue. List name is common for all the sites. But id is different .Anyway is there to pass the id?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create custom form template is by customizing list forms. You can following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223431/Custom-SharePoint-List-Forms) article for steps for developing it.